# add condition with variable inside const IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have following hook that is added on start:

```
const scrollObserver = useCallback(
    (node) => {
        new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((en) => {
                if (en.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                    pagerDispatch({ type: 'ADVANCE_PAGE' }
                }
            })
        }).observe(node)
    },
    [pagerDispatch]
)

useEffect(
    () => {         
        if (bottomBoundaryRef.current) {
            scrollObserver(bottomBoundaryRef.current)
        }
    },
    [scrollObserver, bottomBoundaryRef]
)
```

The problem I'm facing that I want to add `if` condition with a variable value that updates over time. If I add following code then `data.length` is *always* `0`. I guess that's because it has in store the state that was on start.

```
if (en.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
    if (data.length <= iScrollMax) {
        pagerDispatch({ type: 'ADVANCE_PAGE' })
    }
}
```

How do I add condition with updatable variable here?

ps. I've tried making separate fuction but that did not work too.
example

```
function upd() {        
    if (data.length <= iScrollMax) {
        pagerDispatch({ type: 'ADVANCE_PAGE' })
    }
}

const scrollObserver = useCallback(
    (node) => {
        new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((en) => {
                if (en.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                    upd()
                }
            })
        }).observe(node)
    },
    [pagerDispatch]
)
```

Comment: Why can't you use another useEffect with array deps as data and iScrollMax ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I did not quite understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't seeing the updated data value in the function because of closure. Your function is only recreated on change on `pagerDispatch` and so when the data values update, it isn't made aware of it and keeps using the old data value it had when it was created

The solution is to add data as dependency to useCallback and also ensure you cleanup your observer in useEffect

```
const scrollObserver = useCallback(
    (node) => {
        return new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((en) => {
                if (en.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                  if (data.length <= iScrollMax) {
                    pagerDispatch({ type: 'ADVANCE_PAGE' }
                  }
                }
            })
        }).observe(node)
    },
    [pagerDispatch, data]
)

useEffect(
    () => { 
        let observer;        
        if (bottomBoundaryRef.current) {
            observer=scrollObserver(bottomBoundaryRef.current)
        }

       return () => {
           observer && observer.disconnect();
       }
    },
    [scrollObserver, bottomBoundaryRef]
)
```

Approach 2: There is a getaway to this via a ref

```
const dataRef = useRef(data);
useEffect(() => {
   dataRef.current = data;
}, [data]);
const scrollObserver = useCallback(
        (node) => {
            return new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
                entries.forEach((en) => {
                    if (en.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                      if (dataRef.current.length <= iScrollMax) {
                        pagerDispatch({ type: 'ADVANCE_PAGE' }
                      }
                    }
                })
            }).observe(node)
        },
        [pagerDispatch]
    )

    useEffect(
        () => { 
            let observer;        
            if (bottomBoundaryRef.current) {
                observer=scrollObserver(bottomBoundaryRef.current)
            }

           return () => {
               observer && observer.disconnect();
           }
        },
        [scrollObserver, bottomBoundaryRef]
    )
```

Comment: I tried that as well, If I add `[pagerDispatch, data]` then problem here is that subscription to data makes it trigger on every change whilst I need it to check once.

Comment: I updated another approach to it since you only want your subscription to run once. However you must note that in approach 1, you must disconnect the observer

Comment: there was a small "typo" in `if (dataRef.current.length <= iScrollMax`. Changed to `if (dataRef.current <= iScrollMax` and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Just to let you know, this worked because in here the reference is change by mutation instead of having a new reference